# How do I make an object in java for each window/tab/stage that is open on the screen?

Tags: java, tabs, stage

How do I make an object in java for each window/tab/stage that is open on the screen? For example, I want to have 3 objects if I have 1 library and 2 chrome tabs open.

Comment: Could you explain wheteher you are using JavaFx or Swing or any other gui library?

Comment: I'm new to this stuff so I dont really know

Comment: Could you explain your question more in detail as it is really unclear what you are trying to archieve.

Comment: So I want to store information separately for each tab that is open. I am assuming I would have to make a class to be able to make an object. For example, I want to declare Classname obj = new Classname(), obj representing each tab open on my current screen, and then I would be able to store information from each tab into the obj..